# Pipelining a verilog module consisting 10 components connected in series

Tags: verilog, pipeline, digital-design

I am trying to pipeline a module which consists of 5 multipliers and 5 adders connected in series. The module is a polynomial calculator. Without pipelining the module is working perfectly so far.

```
multipliers [31:0] m0,m1,m2,m3,m4; // separate module
adders      [31:0] a0,a1,a2,a3,a4; // separate module
user_input  [31:0] input;          // register
constants   [31:0] c0,c1,c2,c3,c4; // registers
pipeliners  [31:0] p0,p1,p3,p4,p4; // pipelining resisters
wires       [31:0] w0,w1,w2,w3,w4; // wires
```

Without pipelining the structure looks like following,

```
[input]*[c0] => w0 => [w0]+[c1] => w1 => [w1]*[input] => w2 => [w2]+[c2] => w3 ... //goes on like this
```

As all of them are connected in series, the critical path consists of 10 components.

My  implemented pipelining idea is following,

```
[input]*[c0] => w0 => p0 => [p0]+[c1] => w1 => p1 => [p1]*[input] => w2=> p2 => [p2]+[c2] => w3 ... //goes on like this
```

I have an error, "cannot be driven by primitives or continuous assignment."It is due to p0,p1,p3 ... registers. Converting them into wire solves the error but then they are not registers anymore. I am using iverilog as compiler.

My question is, how can I do the pipelining so that I get the output using least possible clock cycles and resolve the error as well?

******* Edited version with code *******

```
`timescale 1ns / 1ps
module poly (
clk,
q,
result
);

input clk;
input [31:0] q; //user input

output [31:0] result;
reg [31:0] c,c0,c1,c2,c3,c4;
reg [31:0] p, p0, p1, p2, p3, p4, p5, p6,p7,p8,p9,p10,p11,p12;

    always @(q)

if (q>=32'h08000000 && q<32'h0A000000) begin

    c <= 32'h058B90C0;
    c0 <= 32'h74599F60; 
    c1 <= 32'h79481740; 
    c2 <= 32'h445B7440; 
    c3 <= 32'h5AF892E0;
    c4 <= 32'h9E2C2258; 

end else  if (q>=32'h0A000000 && q<32'h0C000000) 

begin
    c <= 32'h258B90C0; 
    c0 <= 32'hFB942240; 
    c1 <= 32'h21558EC0; 
    c2 <= 32'h5D882000; 
    c3 <= 32'h75F846E8; 
    c4 <= 32'hF48F5786; 

end

wire  [31:0] x0,x1,x2,x3,x4;
wire  [31:0] y0,y1,y2,y3,y4;

multiplier   m4 (.i_multiplicand(q),.i_multiplier(c4),.o_result(x4));
assign = x4;
adder        a4 (.a(p0),.b(c3),.c(y4));
assign p1 = y4;
assign p2 = q;
multiplier   m3 (.i_multiplicand(p2),.i_multiplier(p1),.o_result(x3));
assign p3 = x3;
adder        a3 (.a(p3),.b(c2),.c(y3));
assign p4 = y3;
assign p5 = q;
multiplier   m2 (.i_multiplicand(p5),.i_multiplier(p4),.o_result(x2));
assign p6 = x2;
adder        a2 (.a(p6),.b(c1),.c(y2));
assign p7 = y2;
assign p8 = q;
multiplier   m1 (.i_multiplicand(p8),.i_multiplier(p7),.o_result(x1));
assign p9 = x1;
adder        a1 (.a(p9),.b(c0),.c(y1));
assign p10 = y1;
assign p11 = q;
adder        a0 (.a(p10),.b(p11),.c(y0));
assign p12 = y0;
multiplier   m0 (.i_multiplicand(p12),.i_multiplier(c),.o_result(x0));

assign result = x0;

endmodule
```

Comment: Calling something a reg in verilog does not mean it is a flip-flop it just has to be driven from an `always` process or 'initial'. using `always @(posedge clk) ` with non-blocking assignments `<=` will mean a flip-flop.

Comment: @Morgan that creates an error "malformed statement" .

Answer (score 0):

As Morgan already stated you get only registers if you have a reg and a clock.

```
always @(posedge clk)
begin
   p1 <= y4;
   p2 <= q;
   // etc.
 end
```

Which if you think about it is rather obvious as this is a register:

[image]

Which as you can see has as input a signal and a clock.